# How do I get the discord.py intents to work?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a bot that welcomes people to the server that it's in and all of the code works except for the on_member_join event because it utilizes the new intents. I googled on how to work with the intents and tried everything but it still isn't working.

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=',', intents = intents)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Your code looks correct (for the members intent). Did you enable the "Server Members Intent" in the developer portal?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=',', intents=intents)
```

You also have to enable privileged intents in the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications)

[A Primer Gateway to Intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html?highlight=intents)

Answer (score 7):

This code will help.

```
intents = discord.Intents().all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=',', intents=intents)
```

**EDIT**
WARN: the code above will use **ALL** intents avaliable

Answer (score 2):

It may be you don't have enabled the permissions.
checkout https://discord.com/developers/applications/

Enable The member's intent permission

- Privileged Gateway Intents

  - SERVER MEMBERS INTENT

Answer (score 0):

The code worked for me after I entered the correct arguments:

```
await message.channel.send(response['choices'][0]['text'])
```