# dicord.py: get_channel() returns None

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am working on a bot which in addition to executing some code should remove reactions added to a specific message.

In the code I wrote, the method `get_channel()` returns `None`.

```
async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
    if payload.message_id == self.message_id['private_room']:
        if payload.emoji.name == self.lock:
            rchannel = self.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
            rmsg = await rchannel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
            ruser = await self.fetch_user(payload.user_id)
            await rmsg.remove_reaction(self.lock, ruser)
```

I can use `await fetch_channel()` method which works fine but as it's an API call it's working much slower (at least I think it is) than the one mentioned above.

EDIT:

I've tried to debug with the following code:

```
print(self.get_user(payload.user_id))
print(await self.fetch_user(payload.user_id))
print(self.get_channel(payload.channel_id))
print(await self.fetch_channel(payload.channel_id))
```

The output is:

```
None
wolex#0000
None
lounge
```

Comment: Is the reaction added in dm's?

Comment: No my bot is intended to work on a server.

Comment: Do you have intents enabled? View [this link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64831017/how-do-i-get-the-discord-py-intents-to-work) if you have not done this.

Comment: I added `members` and `guilds` intents and now it works fine. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had `members` and `guilds` intents disabled. To enable them do the following:

```
intents = discord.Intents.none()
intents.reactions = True
intents.members = True
intents.guilds = True
```

You'll also need ''Privileged Gateway Intents'' enabled. Follow the [official docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html#privileged-intents).

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the **CHANNEL_ID is an int and not a string**.

```
CHANNEL_ID = 746382173
channel = None

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("We have logged in as {0.user}".format(client))
  channel = client.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)
  print(channel)
```