# Discord Channel is not being recognized when using get_channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm trying to make a discord bot that sends a message in a different channel, every time someone joins the server. The bot is recognizing that someone joined but it does not recognize the channel and therefore won't send a message. The channel returns as none when I try to print it, to see if it's being recognized.

```
intents = discord.Intents(members=True)
client=discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event

async def on_member_join(member):
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    channel = client.get_channel(id) 
    print(channel)
  
    print("Recognised that a member called " + member.name + " joined")

    await channel.message.send('Hello' + member.name)
```

Comment: Have you replaced the `id` with you're actual channel id?

Comment: Welcome to Stack rmathews! Have a look at this answer and see if this helps: [discord.py: get_channel() returns None](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65792091/14420546). This person had a similar issue, and all they had to do was enable `guild intents` and `privileged gateway intents`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable [guilds intent](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Intents.guilds) to use `get_channel` method.

```py
intents = discord.Intents(members=True, guilds=True)
client=discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your variables names are screwing you over.

`id` should be a different variable name because `id` is a python keyword. Try `ID` or `id1` or something.

Remember also that the ID must be an integer variable for the function to recognise it.

Comment: `client.get_channel` is not async function. Read the [manual](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.get_channel)