# Discord bot on_join_guild dm everyone

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to dm everyone in the server when the bot is added to the server using the on_join_guild().
The code for it

```
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    for member in guild.members:
        await member.create_dm()
        embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Hi", description="Hello", color=0x00ff00)
        await member.dm_channel.send(embed=embedVar)
```

But whenever I add the bot to server, it dms everyone in the server which is expected but a error also pops in the console.

```
Ignoring exception in on_guild_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Khusi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File ".\time-turner.py", line 42, in on_guild_join
    await member.create_dm()
  File "C:\Users\Khusi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\member.py", line 110, in general
    return getattr(self._user, x)(*args, **kwargs)
AttributeError: 'ClientUser' object has no attribute 'create_dm'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After replicating your code, I found that your error only appears to happen if the bot tries to message itself. You would also get an error if your bot attempts to message another bot (`Cannot send messages to this user`). You can just use `pass` if your bot can't message a user or if it tries to message itself.

```py
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(ctx):
    for member in ctx.guild.members:
        try:
            await member.create_dm()
            embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Hi", description="Hello", color=0x00ff00)
            await member.dm_channel.send(embed=embedVar)
        except:
            pass
```

If the above still doesn't work, just as NerdGuyAhmad had said, you need to enable intents, at the very least member intents. View this link here: [How do I get intents to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64831017/how-do-i-get-the-discord-py-intents-to-work)

Comment: What about intents? Member intents are required to DM every member.

Comment: Yes, this is also true. I will edit this in.