# discord.py How do I get a list of all the servers a user is connected to?

Tags: discord.py

discord.py
How do I get a list of all the servers a user is join to?

i tried it, but failed

```
await ctx.send(str(ctx.author.guilds))
```

but, it failed...

how i get a list of all the servers a user is join to?

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the fastest way to do this, but one way would be to check every guild your bot is in, then check if the `ctx.author` is in that guild. If the author is in that guild, said guild is appended to your list, in this case `shared_guilds`.

```py
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    shared_guilds = []
    for guild in client.guilds:
        if ctx.author in guild.members:
            shared_guilds.append(guild)

    # This is just a clean way to send the message
    message = ""
    for guild in shared_guilds:
        message += f"`{guild.name}` \n"

    await ctx.send(f"Guilds I share with {ctx.author}: \n{message}")
```

The above code works as seen below:

[image: Working Code]

If the above does not work, you may need to enable **intents**. [You can view how to do this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64831017/how-do-i-get-the-discord-py-intents-to-work).

**EDIT**

In discord.py version `1.7`+ there's the [`User.mutual_guilds`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.mutual_guilds) attribute:

```py
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    shared_guilds = ctx.author.mutual_guilds

    # This is just a clean way to send the message
    message = ""
    for guild in shared_guilds:
        message += f"`{guild.name}` \n"

    await ctx.send(f"Guilds I share with {ctx.author}: \n{message}")
```

Version `1.7` it's not yet released, you can either wait till it is, or install it directly from github.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that in discord.py 1.7+ there's the [`User.mutual_guilds`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.mutual_guilds) attribute

Comment: This is true, I will add how to do this in my answer™

Comment: Edit: Not sure how to do this myself, please provide this example if you can

Comment: Simply `ctx.author.mutual_guilds`