# AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'Intents'

Tags: python, discord, bots

i am trying to make an custom bot for my discord server and im getting this error:

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".", intents=discord.Intents.all())
AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'Intents'
```

This is my code:

```
 import discord
 from discord.ext import commands
 from discord import Interaction
 print(discord.__version__)
 client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".", intents= discord.Intents.all())
 
 @client.event
 async def on_ready():
 print(f"{client.user.name} esta preparado ") 

 

 
 client.run("thetokenofthebotrighthere")
```

I tried downgrading, upgrading, and reinstalling discord.py, But, always it shows the same error. I'll try reinstalling python, so wish me luck.

Comment: What part of the error message is unclear? There simply is no `Intents` in `discord`. BTW: You should provide a [mcve] along with the output it produces. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: you should check version of your module - maybe it is too old and it doesn't have `Intents`. Or maybe they removed `Intents` from the newest version and you use old tutorial.

Comment: As mentioned above, make sure to upgrade your discord.py to the latest version. Intents were released in the 1.5 [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66927505/module-discord-has-no-attribute-intents-error?noredirect=1)