# on message event is not triggering

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.id == 872448587571789834:
        data = message.content.split(" ")
        user = re.sub("\D", "", data[0])

        user_object = client.get_user(int(user)) or await client.fetch_user(int(user))
        user = user_object
        await user_object.send("Hey, thanks for up-voting me on top.gg, here take 10,000 coins and a special role as an award ")
        #voted = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name=" Voted for Legend Moderation")
        await open_account(user_object)

        users = await get_bank_data()

        users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] += 10000

        with open("bank.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(users, f, indent=4)
```

The code in here it check if there is a message sent in that specific channel and gets its first username so it can dm that user and give him money
the whole event is not even working i dont get any errors

Comment: Are you sure it's not running? What if you print something before the `if`?

Comment: Doesn't even print

Comment: Do you have multiple `on_message` events?

Comment: yes i have alot of them

Comment: you can only have one on_message event, otherwise, the last one override all the above one.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Discord Dev Portal]

If you do not get any errors when sending a message it's probably because in your bot settings you do not have SERVER MEMBERS INTENT enabled

Once you enabled it in the portal you need to add some code.

Find more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64831017/how-do-i-get-the-discord-py-intents-to-work).

I hope this answer helped you.