# Discordpy mention user from string

Tags: python, discord.py

How can I add an @-mention from a list of strings of users? I want to notify those selected users.

```py
sample_text: @user#tag
```

That will be plain text and its not mentionable. Tried to iterate through members and save it as an object but only the bot is returned.

Example code:

```py
async def on_message(self, message):
(...)
            embed = discord.Embed(title=c.LFG_OVER, description="Party:", color=c.COLOUR_BANANA)
            embed.set_author(name=f"{message.author.display_name}", url="", icon_url=f"{message.author.avatar_url}")
            embed.set_thumbnail(url=c.LFG_TY)

            embed.add_field(name="_", value=f"This is text: {list1[0]}\nThis is text: {list1[1]}\nThis is text: {list2[0]}\nThis is text: {list2[1]}", inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="_", value=f"This is text: {list3[0]}\nThis is text: {dps[1]}\nThis is text: {list3[2]}\nThis is text: {list3[3]}", inline=True)

            await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: You need their user-IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`discord.utils.get`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=utils#discord.utils.get) you can get a member object from their name and # and mention them afterwards using `member.mention`:

```py
#members is your list of members (format is name#1111)
for str_member in members:
    member = discord.utils.get(message.guild.members, name=str_member[:-5], discriminator=str_member[-4:]) 
    #using member.mention you can mention the person now, or save the mention in a list or whatever you want to do
```

Comment: Doing `message.guild.members` would only return the bot itself.

```[<Member id=0000000000 name='Name' discriminator='1068' bot=True nick=None guild=<Guild id=0000000000 name='Name' shard_id=None chunked=False member_count=30>>]```

Comment: Have you enabled member intents, as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64832812/14506951) answer?