# How do i get a discord bot to make and assign roles using Discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to make a bot that makes and assigns a role to the person who requested it. How do I do that? I have tried many things but they all don't work. Here is a copy of the non-functioning code.

```
import discord
import os
from discord.utils import get


client = discord.Client()

@client.event

async def on_ready():
  print ('we have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  if message.content.startswith('~hello?'):
    await message.channel.send('YOU WILL NOW WISH YOU NEVER SUMMONED ME...')
    
client.run(os.environ['TOKEN'])

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
   if message.author == client.user:
        return
        
   if message.content == ('~begin?'):
        role = get(message.server.roles, name=('Admin'))
        await client.add_roles(message.author, role)

client.run(os.environ['TOKEN'])
```

The first part works (~hello?) but the second part (~begin?) doesn't work. Can one of you gracious souls save me from this endless tussle of debugging and coding?

Comment: 1) It is `message.guild.roles` 2) You have to enable/import Intents 3) You have to assign the role to `message.author`

Comment: @Dominik Oops, I was slow :( , if you want to answer it below, tag me and I'll delete mine.

Comment: @Kouheng No problem, just add my parts to your answer/explain them and your answer will also be correct then! :)

Answer (score 0):

I see a few mistakes in your code.

To get back to your question:

1. If you want to get the role in a server you have to request the `guild`, `server` is kind of outdated. In code this means the following:
   `role = message.guild.roles`.

   **Reference:** [Message.guild](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message%20guild#discord.Message.guild)
2. After getting the role we have to assign it to a `member`, this does not work with `client.add_roles`, try `message.author.add_roles()` instead. It'll be `await message.author.add_roles(role)` in the long version then.
3. If you want to assign a role to a member through your bot you also need to enable Intents. There are tons of Contributions on this site but also in the docs, for example:

   - [Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html)
   - [How to get intents to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64831017/how-do-i-get-the-discord-py-intents-to-work)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a command using the `@client.command` function, but first you need to add a prefix to `client by doing

```
client = commands.AutoShardedBot(commands.when_mentioned_or(*prefix*))
```

remember to import commands using from `discord.ext import commands`

then your life would be easy now, if you want to add a command just do

```
@client.command
async def add_role(ctx, member:discord.Member):
  role = get(ctx.guild.roles, name='*the role*')

  await member.add_roles(role)
```

so to call the command just say `*prefix* add_role @*the user*`