# How can I dm a specific User by using Discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py, dm

I'm making a discord bot with discord.py and I want to a specific user when a user uses a specific command.

```
from discord import DMChannel

client = discord.Client()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=']')

@client.command(name='dmsend', pass_context=True)
async def dmsend(ctx, user_id):    
  user = await client.fetch_user("71123221123")
  await DMChannel.send(user, "Put the message here")
```

When I give the command **]dmsend** nothing happens. And I've tried **dmsend** also. But nothing happened.

Comment: are you sure `client.fetch_user("71123221123")` is doing what you think it's doing? Due to the addition of intents, you might need to update the user cache before you are allowed to do something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things I noticed:

You defined `client` twice, that can only go wrong.

**First)** Remove `client = discord.Client()`, you don't need that anymore.

If you want to send a message to a specific user ID, you can't enclose it in quotes. Also, you should be careful with `fetch`, because then a request is sent to the API, and they are limited.

**Second)** Change `await client.fetch_user("71123221123")` to the following:

```py
await client.get_user(71123221123) # No fetch
```

If you have the `user` you want the message to go to, you don't need to create another `DMChannel`.

**Third)** Make `await DMChannel.send()` into the following:

```py
await user.send("YourMessageHere")
```

You may also need to enable the `members` Intent, here are some good posts on that:

- https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html
- [How do I get the discord.py intents to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64831017/how-do-i-get-the-discord-py-intents-to-work)

**A full code, after turning on Intents, could be:**

```py
intents = discord.Intents.all()

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=']', intents=intents)

@client.command(name='dmsend', pass_context=True)
async def dmsend(ctx):
    user = await client.get_user(71123221123)
    await user.send("This is a test")

client.run("YourTokenHere")
```

Comment: So how I mange the `client.run ("token")`

Comment: Just to get it right: You accepted my answer and unaccepted it because you have another question? That is a weird way of handling it. `client.run("YourToken")` has to be at the end of the code, even though this was not part of your question. I just provided the relevant code.

Comment: Oh Sorry bro but when I do it like that it gives me an error..

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: error is too long to type this is the error
[error] (https://ghostbin.com/OHkqK)

Comment: Then you have not read my post. Intents need to be enabled. The error even tells you where to do that. Go to the [Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications), select your `Application`, go to `Bot` -> `Privileged Gateway Intents` and turn them on.

Comment: Oh Thank you I adjust edited the code and now it is working thank you

Comment: Questionable why you have accepted the other answer as correct, because this one is incorrect/respectively not complete. You can only mark one answer as "correct" on StackOverflow.

Comment: Yeah It was a mistake so I undo it :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `await user.send("message")`