# How to add a role to a specific member when he joins a discord server

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

*I'm new to python, so can someone help me with my code, because it is not working properly. When the user that I want joins it doesn't give it a role. I want to make it work for a* **specific** user **only** *to give a role when joining discord server.*

```
   @client.event 
    async def on_member_join(member):
      member = get(member.id, id=member_id)
      role = get(member.guild.roles, id=role_id)
      await member.id(member)
      await member.add_roles(role)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't even know why you're making this so complicated.

Since you already have the `member` as an "argument" you can work with it and don't have to define `member` again.

We can get the ID of `member` very easily with `member.id`. If we want to compare this with a real ID, we do the following:

```py
if member.id = TheIDHere:
    # Do what you want to do
```

The function for the role is correct, yet I cannot find a use for `await member.id(member)`. What is the point of this/has it any use?

How you add the role at the end is also correct, but the code must be indented properly and best you work with an `if / else` statement, otherwise the bot will still give an error at the end in the console if always the wrong `member` joins.

**The whole code:**

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=IDOfTheRole)  # Get the role from member.guild and the id
    if member.id == TheIDHere:  # If the member.id matches
        await member.add_roles(role)  # Add the role for the specific user
    else:  # If it does not match
        return  # Do nothing
```

You may also need to enable the `members` Intent, here are some good posts on that:

- https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html
- [How do I get the discord.py intents to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64831017/how-do-i-get-the-discord-py-intents-to-work)