# Why Does on_member_join Not working with no errors?

Tags: python, discord.py

Well, i was trying to make this event for a while, and couldn't find anything about it!
How do i make this work?

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_join():
    channel = bot.get_channel(908427699595378699)
    await channel.send("We've got a new member!")
```

Comment: You need to have [intents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64831017/how-do-i-get-the-discord-py-intents-to-work) enabled from the [discord developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications).

Answer (score 0):

async def on_member_join(**member**): -- on_member_join takes 1 argument

Answer (score 0):

`async def on_member_join(member):` and `member` is the argument. To send to the specific channel, do `member.channel.send`