# do something when a member connects a voice channel - discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I tried to do something like this randomly, based on the usage of "on_member_join" function, but this didn't work. so, how can I make this work?

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_connect(member):
    channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.voice_channels, name="channel-name")
    print("blabla")
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the docs, [`on_member_join`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_member_join#discord.on_member_join) is not called when a member joins a channel, it is called when a user joins a guild/server.

`on_member_connect` is not an event on discord.py, what you are looking for is [`on_voice_state_update`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_voice_state_update).

```py
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if before.channel is None and after.channel:
       # User has connected to a VoiceChannel
       channel = after.channel
       # Code here...
```

Comment: firstly, thank you! And I am sorry but, I couldnt figure it out how to complete this code.. I put a simple print() function where you wrote "# code here..." but it didn't work :/ Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @Kyroic can *you* explain more? specifically what do you mean by it didn't work? you joined the channel and the message wasn't printed? make sure your [intents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64832812/13123877) are correctly set-up

Comment: Yes, when I join the channel, the message is not getting printed. 

intents = discord.Intents(messages=True, guilds=True, reactions=True, members=True, presences=True)
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!",intents=intents)

And here is my intents setup, is there anything wrong here? I am not sure. @WasiMaster

Comment: @Kyroic why don't you just do `intents = discord.Intents.all()`. Do that and see what happens

Comment: @WasiMaster oh, it's done!! thank you! Intents.all() worked!