# Check all members custom status instead of just my custom status

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How could I change this command to check the custom status of all the members in the server instead of just checking the custom status of the person that wrote the command

The code that works gets my custom status which was `test` and it prints it out perfectly fine. I just want to know if/how I could get the custom status of everyone in the server.

```
@bot.command()
async def checkstatus(ctx):
    for status in ctx.author.activities:
        if isinstance(status, discord.CustomActivity):
            print(status)
```

```
Logged in as vanity#####
test
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate through all the members in your server ([`ctx.guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=guild#discord.abc.GuildChannel.guild)) in another `for` loop.

```py
@bot.command()
async def checkstatus(ctx):
    for member in ctx.guild.members: # for every member in the server,
        for status in member.activities: # for every status that member has..
            # then the rest of your code below
```

Do also note that you need to [enable member intents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64832812/14420546) to view all the members.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use a selfbot? If yes, they are against ToS, but you could use [discord.py-self](https://github.com/dolfies/discord.py-self)