# Discord.py bot not sending messages in a discord server but sends messages in DM's

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a discord.py bot that when the command is sent through DM, it works. When the command is ran through a server, nothing happens. There is no errors or tracebacks. Here is my code so far.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = discord.Bot()

TOKEN = "MyToken"

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$")

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

I don't know whats happening. I gave it the right permissions but it still wont do anything.

Comment: Enable your [intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=client#discord.Intents) in the developer portal and configure it in your bot.

Comment: @3nws how do I do that?

Comment: Check [How do I get the discord.py intents to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64831017/how-do-i-get-the-discord-py-intents-to-work).

Comment: What is your discordpy version? If there's no errors, I would assume it's not the version where you get message intents yet. You should probably upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: @EricJin my version is 1.7.3, the latest version

Comment: Why do you have `discord.Bot` and also the commands bot? I think you’re only supposed to use the commands bot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, I believe you have fiddled it up by using the `bot =` variable twice, in two different ways. The way I would do it is as following:

First, import our libraries and define the token:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = "MyToken"
```

Next, we need to set up the `bot` variable, as so:

```py
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=discord.Intents.all()) # I usually add all intents, you can use discord.Intents.default if you like.
```

I add intents because Discord sometimes gets angry if you do not, so I like to make it a just in case backup.

Now, we create the command:

```py
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)
```

And lucky last, log into our bot:

```py
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Prior to our command, you can enter an on_ready function to verify the bot has logged in correctly:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"{bot.user} logged in successfully.")
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I don't know *for sure* if this is the issue, but try this:

I have my bot set as:

```py
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix= '$', description="<desc>")
```

Rather than yours which is BOTH of these:

```py
bot = discord.Bot()
```

&

```py
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$")
```

I think it's only detecting the first value you've given your bot.