# I can't use ping in discord.py

Tags: discord.py

My code is run bot is online.But command can't

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
     print('Logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.command(description='ping')
async def ping(ctx):
     await ctx.send(f'{round(client.latency*1000)}ms')

client.run(!@#$$%)
```

Comment: You need to enable message intents. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64831241/9083371)

Comment: I have added the code but just now it throws an error in the `client.run()` part.I have TOKEN

Comment: Update your question with your error, we can't help if we don't know what it is

Answer (score -1):

First of all, a **prefixed command cannot have a description inside the command decorator**...
If you want it to have one in the Help Command do something like this:

```
@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
  """Shows the current latency of the bot"""
```

Then, could you post the error message if raised?

Anyways, try using this:

```
@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
  """Shows the current latency of the bot"""
  await ctx.typing()
  ping = client.latency*1000
  embed = discord.Embed(title=" || ¡Pong!", description="Latency:\n{}ms".format(ping), color=ctx.author.color)
  await ctx.reply(embed=embed)
```

Any other thing that you dont understand, isnt clear, etc. tell to me via comments, ill edit my answer as fast as possible

Comment: I tried it but in description=f"Latency:\n{}ms" code error in {}

Comment: ye, forgot to remove the `f`, take a look in a fiew segs

Comment: i tried again the code has run but im use .ping bot not responding

Comment: Unless things have changed recently, you can definitely use `description` and `brief` inside the command decorator. You just also have the option of using the docstring

Comment: description and brief are part of dpy rewrite, change your tags instead of using dpy only...