# How do I use intents in discord's Python API

Tags: python, discord

I have tried running this script without the intents at first, but then VS Code told me that I needed it without giving me any hint as to what to put after intents.

Code:

```
import discord
client = discord.Client(intents=)

@client.event
async def on_connect():
    for user in client.user.friends:
        try:
            await user.send("MESSAGE")
            print(f"Working with: {user.name}")
        except:
            print(f"Not working on: {user.name}")

client.run("Tokennothereforprivacy" , bot=False)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the discord.py intents to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64831017/how-do-i-get-the-discord-py-intents-to-work)

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to this:

First, you need to enable which intents you need in the Discord Developer portal. This is under Bots > **Privileged Gateway Intents**. Next, you need to go in your code, and type in the intents.

For example, if you just selected Message Content Intent, you would put this next to intents: `message_content=True`
Altogether, it would be:

```
client = discord.Client(intents= message_content = True)
```

If you have more than 1 intent, use commas to separate them, like this

```
(intents= intent1 = True, intent2 = True)
```

I hope this helped.