# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_roles'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    print("Reaction detected")
    print(f"payload.user_id: {str(payload.user_id)}")
    print(f"payload.message_id: {str(payload.message_id)}")
    print(f"payload.emoji.name: {str(payload.emoji.name)}")
    guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g: g.id == payload.guild_id, client.guilds)
    
    if payload.emoji.name == "" and payload.message_id == 1095071488282992831:
        role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=1094731340383002694)
        member = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)
        await member.add_roles(role) #line 72
```

I'm getting the error on Line 72 saying 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_roles'. I know this means the 'member' variable somehow failed, but I don't have a clue how it failed. The output also printed this:

```
Reaction detected
payload.user_id: 692156420895801495
payload.message_id: 1095071488282992831
payload.emoji.name:
```

Can someone help?

Comment: I would guess that `guild.get_member()` returned a null result, because that guild does not have that member...

Comment: Ik that, but idk why it would return null

Comment: If that guild does not have that member, then what else would you expect it to do?

Comment: The member is not stored in the guild cache. You probably didn't set `intents.members = True`

Comment: Do not capitalize variable names and you are also using `add_roles` incorrectly. This function only takes the `role` argument.

Comment: In the documentation, it shows the variables capitalized (it says discord.Member in the Member documentation)

Comment: Added ```intents.member = True``` right below the print statement but got NameError: name 'intents' is not defined

Comment: Removed ```intents.member = True``` and made the variables all lowercase and made the arguments of add_roles() just add_roles(role). The same error happened.

Comment: I edited the original post with the changes

Comment: @YozyOpto Capitalized names are used for class names. That's why in the documentation you see `discord.Member`. But instances of a class must have a name in lower case.

Comment: See this post to learn how to set the intents: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64831017/how-do-i-get-the-discord-py-intents-to-work

Comment: I got an error saying "module 'discord' has no attribute 'Intents' "

Comment: It looks like you are using a very old version of [discord.py](https://pypi.org/project/discord.py/). Make sure you are using the latest version.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: I've added a reply to your post so we can discuss there.

Answer (score 0):

In order for you to get members from a server using [guild.get_member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.get_member) they need to be stored in the bot's cache. To make this happen, enable the members intent:

```py
from discord.ext import commands
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    print("Reaction detected")
    print(f"payload.user_id: {payload.user_id}")
    print(f"payload.message_id: {payload.message_id}")
    print(f"payload.emoji.name: {payload.emoji}")
    if payload.message_id == 1095071488282992831 and str(payload.emoji) == "":
        guild = bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
        role = guild.get_role(1094731340383002694)
        member = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)
        await member.add_roles(role)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 10, in <module>
    intents = discord.Intents.default()
AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'Intents'

Comment: ```
import os
import discord
from keep_alive import keep_alive
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import logging
import time
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

# When IP abuse occurs, type "kill 1" in the Shell tab.

logging.basicConfig(
  format="%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(message)s",
  level=logging.INFO,
)
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!!", intents=intents)
```

This is the top of my code btw

Comment: You will need to update your discord.py version. Run the command `pip install discord.py --upgrade`

Comment: If you don't know how to upgrade a python library, check out some docs on the internet, like this one: https://blog.finxter.com/easy-way-to-update-a-python-package-with-pip-upgrade/

Comment: File "<stdin>", line 1 pip install discord.py --upgrade
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I think the mistake is that you are running that code in the python shell instead of the Command Prompt. Try running that same code in Command Prompt/Terminal and the package should install.

Comment: How did you install discord.py? The process to update is similar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253113/discussion-between-yozy-opto-and-hazzu).