# Error "AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'Intents'"

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I keep getting this error and can't figure out what will fix it. I use [Replit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replit) to host my Discord bot, so it should automatically update to the latest `discord.py` library. I also tried to check `guilds` on in the URL generator in the developer portal, but it asked me for a redirect URI and would error whenever I tried to provide it. I've tried everything at this point to get this to work, so how do I do this?

**Original Question:**

['NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_roles'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75981981/nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-add-roles/75990730)

```
import os
import discord
from keep_alive import keep_alive
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import logging
import time
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

# When IP abuse occurs, type "kill 1" in the Shell tab.

logging.basicConfig(
  format="%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(message)s",
  level=logging.INFO,
)
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!!", intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("I'm in")
```

Comment: ```print(f"Version: {discord.__version__}"```

Version: 1.3.4

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your comment, the reason is [`discord.Intents`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Intents) only exist on versions [`1.5`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/whats_new.html#v1-5-0) and higher.  So this package does not get updated properly. Go in the Replit terminal, and type `pip3 install discord.py --upgrade`, and make sure it installs the newest version of the library.

You will also need to enable intents in the [Discord developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications). Go to your application, and under the **Bot** section enable the privileged gateway intents that you will need (based on your code above, it looks like you will require the **Server Members Intent**).

[image: Privileged Gateway Intents]

Comment: Where's the replit terminal? I tried inserting that into the console and it errored

Comment: ```None is requesting privileged intents that have not been explicitly enabled in the developer portal. It is recommended to go to https://discord.com/developers/applications/ and explicitly enable the privileged intents within your application's page. If this is not possible, then consider disabling the privileged intents instead.``` How do I do this? I went to the page and can't find intents

Comment: When I typed that in, it updated but now the bot seems to REQUIRE intents and won't work at all now

Comment: For some reason it's showing 'discord' has no attribute 'Intents' again. I updated it and now when I try to update it says ```no such option: --update```

Comment: Ohhhhhh whoops.

Comment: It said ```Successfully installed aiohttp-3.8.4 async-timeout-4.0.2 discord.py-2.2.2``` but the version is still 1.3.4

Comment: No not yet sadly