# Slash commands working somehow but they're not working

Tags: discord.py

So i was asking bard (https://bard.google.com/) I told the AI "Can you give me slash commands" Then he gave me the code, The code was not working so i decided to remove the slash commands and run the bot already, Somehow they worked, but the response was not working, Can you guys give me a way on how to remove the old slash commands and replace it with the new beautiful slash commands??

NOTE: This one is discord.py, Not any kind of other code languages

The error is this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\asdasdggg\Desktop\nice.py", line 61, in <module>
    @bot.application_command()
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'application_command'. Did you mean: 'application_flags'?
```

Comment: Answer fast please.

Answer (score 2):

That is not the correct implementation of a slash command (application command). AI chat bots like bard may give inaccurate or outdated information sometimes and should not be relied on for programming.

There are two ways of creating slash commands, with `discord.Client` or `commands.Bot`

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands

client = discord.Client()
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)
```

With `commands.Bot`

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot()
tree = bot.tree
```

And with both, app commands look like this

```
@tree.command(name=“mycommand”, description=“description”)
async def mycommand(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(content=“Hello World”) #  Requiring a response
```

Slash commands also have to be synced before they appear.

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await tree.sync()
```

For your sake, I recommend learning the basics of Python before going into things like Discord.py.

Also see [How to set up Intents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64831017/how-do-i-get-the-discord-py-intents-to-work), and [app_commands.CommandTree.sync](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.app_commands.CommandTree.sync).