# problem with bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

Tags: python, discord

"bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')" is giving me a "Parameter 'intents' unfilled" error and I don't know how to fix it.

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')


@bot.command()
async def info(ctx):

    """
    ctx - context (information about how the command was executed)
    /info
    """

    await ctx.send(ctx.guild)
    await ctx.send(ctx.author)
    await ctx.send(ctx.message.id)


bot.run('TOKEN')
```

I'm trying to tell you the guild author and message id when you use !info

Comment: You must provide an `intents` parameter, it's currently missing. https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html

Comment: similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64831017/how-do-i-get-the-discord-py-intents-to-work